# Is it possible to define a system of Diophantine equations for Rowland's prime sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

[Rowland's sequence](https://oeis.org/wiki/Rowland%27s_sequence) is a very well-known recurrence formula able to generate an infinite [set of prime numbers](http://oeis.org/A137613) (based on the use of the greatest common divisor).

In the other hand, please correct me if this is wrong, this sequence is a [computably enumerable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set), and a computably enumerable set, by [Matiyasevich's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem), can be obtained from a system of Diophantine equations. Thus, from that system, a polynomial of a given degree could be constructed similar to [the one defined by Jones et al. (1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formula_based_on_a_system_of_Diophantine_equations) to obtain the complete set of prime numbers.

For that reason I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Is it correct to conclude that there must be a system of Diophantine equations able to obtain the same set of Rowland primes?
> 2. Probably there is not previous research about it but, are there any references about that possible system of equations? Did some researcher tried to define it? (I did not find any papers regarding that possibility, any references are very welcomed).
> 3. Having in mind the "simplicity" of Rowland's recurrence formula applied to obtain the primes, would the system of Diophantine equations be easier to be defined than [the one defined by Jones et al. (1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formula_based_on_a_system_of_Diophantine_equations) able to obtain the complete set of prime numbers?

I would like to confirm if at least theoretically this is possible or not. Probably the definition of the Diophantine system is quite complex. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I think (but I am not sure) the polynomial you mentioned was derived directly from the definition of a prime, so I do not think that a (much) easier polynomial will exist. But if you find one and can construct a very large prime (lets say with $10^{10}$ digits) you can become rich and famous at the same time (I think there are still awards for very large primes)

Comment: @Peter thank you very much for the feedback! but... who wants to be rich? :) the reason of my question is that, according to Jones (1982), Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#CITEREFJones1982) there also exists such a set of equations to generate the polynomial of primes of degree only 4, but in 58 variables. If the Diophantine version of Rowland's sequence could be represented with a lower set of variables that would be a good step imho.

Comment: "who wants to be rich?" , that's a good one! Maybe, there is a better polynomial. I think, noone knows.